# GLSL Shader will not render color from uniform variable

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I am currently building an app for Android, but have run into some problems with a shader that refuses to render.

Consider the following fragment shader:

```
uniform vec4 color;
void main(){
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0);
}
```

This shader works fine for drawing an object in a solid color (white in this case). The uniform vector `color` is optimized away, and cannot be found with `glGetUniformLocation()` (returns -1).

Trying to get the color from the uniform variable can be done like so:

```
uniform vec4 color;
void main(){
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

However, when I use this, nothing renders. The shader is created successfully and `glGetUniformLocation()` returns a valid value (0) for color. But nothing shows on screen, not even black. The only change made is replacing `vec4(1.0)` with `color`.
This code has the same result:

```
uniform vec4 color;
void main(){
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0)+color;
}
```

The strange thing is that when I tried the shader in a different project, it works as it should, so the problem must be something I do elsewhere in the code.
This is my drawing method (keep in mind that it works when the color-variable is not in the shader):

```
GLES20.glUseProgram(colorshader);
GLES20.glUniform4f(colorIndex, 1, 1, 1, 1); //colorIndex is the result of glGetUniformLocation() called with the correct shader index and variable name.

Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix, 0, vpMatrix, 0, matrix, 0);
GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixindex, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices);
GLES20Fix.glVertexAttribPointer(Shader.ATTRIBUTE_VERTEX, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 12, 0);

GLES20.glLineWidth(width);
GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_LINES, 0, count);
```

I have absolutely no idea what might be causing this odd behaviour, if anyone have any ideas or possible solutions, please help me.

**Update:**
It seems that using any uniform variable that is not a sampler causes this behaviour in this (and only this) shader.

**Update 2**
Using `glGetError()` return error code `502: GL_INVALID_OPERATION`.

Comment: "But nothing shows on screen, not even black." That suggests an error somewhere. Did you check for errors?

Comment: @NicolBolas: My thoughts exactly, I do not get any explicit errors when creating the shader, and as I can get a value for the color uniform it must be something that goes wrong later in the process. Unfortunately I don't know how to debug this. Would `glGetError()` be of any help in the code perhaps?

Comment: `glGetError` is what you should use.

Comment: Also, you did *use* the program, right? You called `glUseProgram` before calling that rendering function, yes? Because all the `glUniform` functions modify the program that's currently in use.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Right, I will post an update after I have tested a bit more with that then. And yes, I do call `glUseProgram()` before anything (added that line in my post above).

Comment: @NicolBolas: I did some error searching and finally figured it out (see update and the answer I posted) Thanks for helping me out. I have been struggling with this since yesterday :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I finally figured it out after a load of testing.
In my code, I was using *multiple shaders*, but I had accidentally only got the mvpMatrix-uniform for *one* shader and was using that one for every shader, which funnily enough worked for all shaders I had before creating this one (it got id 0 for all the earlier shaders).
However with this shader it seems that my new vec4 got id 0, which caused the code to wrongly assign my vector data to the mvp-matrix. getting new ids for each shader made the program work.

Answer (score -4):

color is uninitialized, and most likely the shader aborts.

Comment: If colorIndex holds it, it's not uninitialized. However, I didn't interpret the rendering code that way, which may have been wrong. I would still try initializing the color-vector in the shader to see if that has any effect.

Comment: colorindex holds a valid value for the variable, so it is initialized properly.

Comment: @Tobias He clearly writes in an in-code comment that `colorIndex` comes from `glGetUniformLocation` (which, like he said in the question, returns 0) and uses this in `glUniform4f`. So I cannot see how it could be uninitialized in any way. Of course he have to trust his statements, but well. It may well be a good guess that it's indeed uninitialized, but at a whole not good enough for an answer. A comment would clearly have sufficed to clear the grey areas up.